# how to increase location accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation, normalization, accuracy

I am developing a website for student attendance if a student is present in classroom in given time and he/she fill attendance by pressing a button then his/her attendance should be marked as present.

I am doing it by accessing location of user...

I am using geolocation API to access location of user :https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation

it returns value like :
Latitude: 20.7819165
Longitude: 22.5789159

but many times it gives different values for the same point of location(varying last four digits) and I can't find any criteria to differentiate user who is inside the classroom and outside the classroom

[image]

Almost same value of for both points in above image
Is Machine learning is useful to solve it ?
Or any other way to do it ?

Comment: I don't think this is really related to this website but i'll give you an idea of how to get maybe a completmentary location. If you can know precisely where are the routers of the different wifi networks of the uni, you can use the wifi networks to triangulate user position, probably allowing to reduce uncertainty of gps location. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485370/wi-fi-position-triangulation)